# Obtaining wrong analog readings using the ESP32 devkitc v4

Tags: esp32, espressif

I know that the topic is not related to Arduino, but I am completely sure that someone can help me find the problem.
I am testing 6 temperature sensors (3 digital, 3 analog). The digital ones are "DS18B20" which I trust, the analog ones are "MCP9701A", "TC1047A" and "MCP9700A".
By reading the analog sensors using Arduino-UNO or Arduino-mega the results of the 6 sensors are almost identical and I don't face any problem. But when make the test using the ESP32-devkitc-v4 I obtain wrong reading from the 3 analog sensors. In the code "serial monitor" I obtain a voltage value completely different from the one I measure physically by a multi-meter

For example :
The 3 digital sensors a giving the value of 23.56C to 23.81C but for the "MCP9701A" analog sensor I obtain 16.26C and the voltage obtain in the serial monitor is 0.718 volts, however it is 0.851 volts by the multi-meter. And according to the calculations from the data-sheet: (0.851-0.4)/(19.5mVolts)= 23.12C which is so close to the digital sensors. I have the same problem with the other analog sensors, so if you can help me find my error, I will appreciate it.

Here are the data-sheets of the analog sensors:

**MCP9701A and MCP9711A**

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001942G.pdf

**TC1047A**

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21498D.pdf

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "driver/adc.h"

// GPIO where the DS18B20 is connected to
const int oneWireBus = 4;     
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature sensor 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

#define analogInPin0 35
#define analogInPin1 32
#define analogInPin2 33

float analogTempTC1047=0.0;
float analogTempMCP9700=0.0;
float analogTempMCP9701=0.0;

float volt0=0.0;
float volt1=0.0;
float volt2=0.0;

int sensorValue0 = 0;
int sensorValue1 = 0;
int sensorValue2 = 0;

void setup() {
  // Start the Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Start the DS18B20 sensor
  sensors.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sensorValue0 = analogRead(analogInPin0);
  sensorValue1 = analogRead(analogInPin1);
  sensorValue2 = analogRead(analogInPin2);

  volt0= (3.3/4096.0)*sensorValue0;
  analogTempMCP9701= ((volt0-0.4)/0.0195);

  volt1= (3.3/4096.0)*sensorValue1;
  analogTempTC1047= ((volt1-0.5)/0.01);
  
  volt2= (3.3/4096.0)*sensorValue2;
  analogTempMCP9700= ((volt2-0.5)/0.01);

  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float temperatureC1 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  float temperatureC2 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(1);
  float temperatureC3 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(2);
  Serial.print("S1= ");
  Serial.print(temperatureC1);
  Serial.print("ºC");
  Serial.print(", S2= ");
  Serial.print(temperatureC2);
  Serial.print("ºC");
  Serial.print(", S3= ");
  Serial.print(temperatureC3);
  Serial.print("ºC,------- ");

  Serial.print("input sensor1= ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue0);
  Serial.print(", volt1=  ");
  Serial.print("= ");
  Serial.print(volt0, 3);
  Serial.print(", Analog sensor MCP9701 = ");
  Serial.print(analogTempMCP9701);

  Serial.print("----");
  Serial.print("input sensor2= ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue1);
  Serial.print(", volt2=  ");
  Serial.print("= ");
  Serial.print(volt1, 3);
  Serial.print(" --Analog sensor TC1047 = ");
  Serial.print(analogTempTC1047);
  
  Serial.print("----");
  Serial.print("input sensor3= ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue2);
  Serial.print(", volt2=  ");
  Serial.print("= ");
  Serial.print(volt2, 3);
  Serial.print(" --Analog sensor MCP9700 = ");
  Serial.println(analogTempMCP9700);
  delay(4000);
}
```

**And here is the serial monitor output:**

```
S1= 23.56ºC, S2= 23.81ºC, S3= 23.50ºC,------- input sensor1= 895, volt1=  = 0.721, Analog sensor MCP9701 = 16.47----input sensor2= 747, volt2=  = 0.602 --Analog sensor TC1047 = 10.18----input sensor3= 752, volt2=  = 0.606 --Analog sensor MCP9700 = 10.59
S1= 23.56ºC, S2= 23.75ºC, S3= 23.50ºC,------- input sensor1= 894, volt1=  = 0.720, Analog sensor MCP9701 = 16.42----input sensor2= 747, volt2=  = 0.602 --Analog sensor TC1047 = 10.18----input sensor3= 755, volt2=  = 0.608 --Analog sensor MCP9700 = 10.83
S1= 23.56ºC, S2= 23.75ºC, S3= 23.50ºC,------- input sensor1= 905, volt1=  = 0.729, Analog sensor MCP9701 = 16.88----input sensor2= 746, volt2=  = 0.601 --Analog sensor TC1047 = 10.10----input sensor3= 753, volt2=  = 0.607 --Analog sensor MCP9700 = 10.67
```

Comment: see if your 4095 code is really 3.3v and not 3.15v or something. Keep in mind that the shoulders and toes of esp32 adcs are a little sluggish too. `0.851v / (895/4095)` is 3.89v, so something is off on the ceiling

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, only a direction to consider:

The ESP32 ADC seems to be shipped with a ADC calibration tolerance of ±6%, as stated in the [ESP32 datasheet, chapter 4.1.2](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf#2f). [Here are the calibration docs.](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html#adc-calibration)

It seems like you're still off by more than those 6% (didn't calculate it through). Maybe your power supply is a bit weak, pulling the internal reference voltage down?